# plotly: download png button not working

Tags: r, shiny, png, plotly

I'm using the package plotly (v.3.6.0) with shiny (v.0.13.2) and the download png button not working neither with chrome (version: 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit) Mac) nor Safari. The same problem for windows with chrome and IE.
I have these two messages:

Taking snapshot - this may take a few seconds

Sorry there was a problem downloading your png.

This is an example data

```
    data <- data.frame(x=rep(c('A14','B15','C16'), each = 1, times = 3), y=runif(90, 50, 100),group=rep(c('2014','2015','2016'), each = 1, times= 3))
```

and this is the code

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
shinyUI(
fluidPage(    
titlePanel("Barchart"),
sidebarLayout(      
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("year", "A-year:", levels(data[,1])),
    hr()),
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("dataPlot")  
  ))))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
output$dataPlot <- renderPlotly({
p <- plot_ly(data, x = input$year, y=y, group=group,type = "bar")
p})
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe give the dev version a shot? See [this](http://community.plot.ly/t/download-png-not-working-in-r-shiny/1574)